# can't link a button to EXIT icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I am learning how to create unwind segue. I created two VCs, „ViewoController“ and „MessageViewController“. The first one contains a button while the latter is embedded in a NavigationController and it has two barButtons „Cancel“ and Save“.

As far as I know, to create the unwind segue, the „Cancel“ and/or the „Save“ buttons in „MessageViewController“ must be linked to the EXIT icon in its ViewController which „MessageViewController“.

The problem I have is, when I can not link the barButton to the EXIT icon

please let me know how to link the barBurron to the EXIT icon in order to have the method "backToViewController" called

**viewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MessageViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonNext;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a 
nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 -(void) backToViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

 }

 @end
```

**messageViewController**:

```
 #import "MessageViewController.h"
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface MessageViewController ()

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem    
 *barButtonSave;

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem   
 *barButtonCancel;

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField 
 *textFieldMessage;
 @end

 @implementation MessageViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature is *not quite right*. In order for Xcode to recognize it for use as an Exit / Unwind Segue, it needs to return `IBAction`.

Changing it to:

```
- (IBAction) backToViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
```

should solve your problem.